# Node.js - Create Relationships with Mongoose from different file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two Schemas `Products` and `Users` in different files. `Products` are belong to `User` and `User` have many `Product`

The Problem is, I have try to use Populate but somehow it return not what I expected.

here is my Schema for Product on models *products.js*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var users = require('../models/users');

var Product = mongoose.Schema({
  user_id : {type: String, required: true },
  category_id : {type: String, default: null},
  title : {type: String, required: true },
  content : {type: String, default : "" },
  pictureUrls : Array,
  counter : {type : Number, default : 0},,
  lowercaseTitle : {type: String, default : null },
  _user : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: users.User }
});

Product.set('toObject', {
  getters: true,
  virtuals: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', Product)
```

and this is my Schema for User on models *users.js*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var User = mongoose.Schema({
  firstName : {type: String, default: "" },
  lastName : {type: String, default: "" },
  username : {type: String, required: true },
  email : {type: String, required: true },
  password : {type: String, default: "" },
  bio : {type: String, default: "" },
  website : {type: String, default: "" },
  phone : {type: String, default: "" },
  gender : {type: String, default: "" },
  birthDate : {type: Date, default: null },
  avatarUrl : {type: String, default: "" },
  verified : {type : Boolean, default : false}
});

User.set('toObject', {
  getters: true,
  virtuals: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

currently I am using method find by calling each Models

```
User.findOne({"sessionToken" : bearerHeader}, function (err, user){
  Product.find({"user_id" : user._id}, function (err, products){
    console.log(products);
  });
});
```

but it takes time and became problem if there related to another models.
I'm calling populte with this

```
 Product.findOne({}).populate('_user').exec(function(err, p){
    console.log(p);
  });
```

but attribute `_user` was not set and undefined

any help?
Thanks

Comment: I think that your ref is wrong since it reference to the uset model not to the schema as it should

Comment: @Molda thanks for your answer, I found the solution by directly use the mongoose Schema, which in this case

`_user : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }`